# setInterval not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, setinterval, anonymous-function

I can't figure out why its says `ajaxcall()` doesn't exist, but the 
        `$('button').click(function(){
                ajaxcall();
            });` works just fine

```
var nameid = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
            ajaxcall();
        });
    function ajaxcall(){
        $.get('mysqlquery.php?id='+nameid, function(data){
            $('#loadbox').append(data+'  ');
        });
        nameid++; 

    }
    setInterval("ajaxcall",1000);
});
```

Please help me understand why, I think it has to do with scope But I'm stumped. (may be time for a break)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the function *outside* of `document.ready`, and use the overload of `setInterval` that takes a function reference:

```
var nameid = 1;

function ajaxcall() {
    $.get('mysqlquery.php?id='+nameid, function(data){
        $('#loadbox').append(data+'  ');
    });
    nameid++; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
            ajaxcall();
        });
    setInterval(ajaxcall,1000);
});
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to call the function without the `()` or do you have any source to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

Call `setInterval` without the quotes for the `function` argument. (Preferred Method)

**Example**:

```
setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000);
```

If you're calling it with the quotes you need to include the parenthesis.
But this forces `eval()` to be called.

**Example**:

```
setInterval("ajaxcall()", 1000);
```

The *former* is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around "ajaxcall" to pass the actual function to setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

or use the code below

replace setInterval line to

```
setInterval(function() {
$.get('mysqlquery.php?id='+nameid, function(data){
        $('#loadbox').append(data+'  ');
    });
    nameid++; 
}, 1000);
```

or use this

```
setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000);
```

or use this

```
setInterval("ajaxcall()", 1000);
```

hoep this helps